# extract substring from extras and append to another variable

Tags: android, string, android-intent

After days of research and numerous compiler errors... i think i need some assitance from the community.

I have a simple app that retrieves a url through a shared intent from another app.
I want to extract a value from the intent's stringextra (which is a url) add it to the end of my script's url and send that final string as a URL to an URLconnection httpget request.

I've defined my script's url as a variable.
I've gotten the intent and its extras and put it in a variable.
I've tried to just concat my url variable and the stringextra variable to no avail,
URLconnectio gave me back a MalformedURLException. I've logged the concat'd variable
and it looked exactly like what i wanted but for some reason it wouldn't go through.

So now, I'm attempting to just cut the piece I need off of the stringextra and put it on my script's url and then make the http get request off that newly formed string.
SO....
how do I extract 11 characters after "v=", which is in the stringextra, which is
a variable called sharedText?

```
    String goLoQooUrl = "http://my.domain.my/script.php?link=";


    private static final String TAG = "LTV";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Intent rIntent = getIntent();
    String rAction = rIntent.getAction();
    String rType = rIntent.getType();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(rAction) && "text/plain".equals(rType))
    displaySentText(rIntent);

    }

private void displaySentText (Intent rIntent) {
    String sharedText = rIntent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    if (sharedText == null) return;
    if (sharedText.startsWith("http://")) {
    TextView url = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.URL);
    url.setText(String.valueOf(sharedText));

    ****String w = goLoQooUrl+SUBSTRING***** this is what I want
    Log.d("TAG", w);

    };
    playOnLoqooTv(w);
    }

private void playOnLoqooTv (String w) { 
   try {
          StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
          StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
          StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
          URL url = new URL(w);
```

I've tried numerous things to no avail
namely tried using the substring method and it gave me an error about that method
wasn't available I probably wasn't calling it correct.

Can any Masters of the Universes', shed some light?

Comment: have you tried the command split ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:-

```
int indexOfv = sharedText.indexOf("="); // Get the index of =
indexOfv++; // To get the substring after this element.
String subString = sharedText.substring(indexOfv, indexOfv+11); //Get the 11 characters after the = sign.
```

Comment: thX! that did it but it also came with the = sign so i prollie have to do +10 or +12

Comment: are there 2 `equals` symbol there? If not, then the `=` symbol won't come. The `indexOfv++;` is specifically meant to skip that only. Can you show the full text present in `sharedText`?

Comment: there sometimes could be two or three equals signs depending on the url that is included in stringextras...sometimes it'll be this "//http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d22AslL0ZdY//" and sometimes itll be this "//http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etmzOOtNCIk&list=RD023pyuFfKPCvY//"

Comment: +10 didnt work and +12 niether, whats happening is the = is being including but the correct 11th character is being left off, so that formula is excluding the last character of the id